# Socket IO server neither emits nor receive any message to/from client : MEAN with ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat, mean-stack

I am writing a chat app using MEAN stack, however i got stuck while implementing them. The server is not getting any kind of update from client neither it sends any thing to client. I guess there is some error in server, but could not figure it out any where.

The server.js file is :-

```
 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
  var express = require('express'),
  neo4j = require('node-neo4j'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),

  app = express();

 //socket io integration
 var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
 var clients = [];
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.sendfile('./index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket)
{
 console.log("Server : Connected to Socket IO");
 console.info('New client connected (id=' + socket.id + ').');

 socket.on('user enter',function(user_name){
  clients.push({id:socket.id,userName:user_name});
  len=clients.length;
  io.emit('user entrance',clients,clients[len-1].id);
});

socket.on('send msg',function(data){
   socket.broadcast.to(data.id).emit('get msg',{msg:data.msg,id:data.id,name:data.name});
  });

   socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
      console.log("user disconnected :" +data.id);
  })
});

app.use(require("express").static('data'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

 app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
 applogger.info('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
 });

});
```

The client side code (chatController.js) is -

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ChatCtrl',function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams,socket,$ionicScrollDelegate,$timeout) {

$scope.userName = $scope.user.name;

socket.on('connect',function()
{
  console.log("from userListCtrl : "+ JSON.stringify($rootScope.selectedUser));
  $scope.selected_id=$rootScope.selectedUser;

});

socket.emit('user enter',$scope.userName);

  socket.on('user entrance',function(data,my_id){
  //checking the user id
  if($scope.my_id==null){
    $scope.my_id=my_id;
  }
  $scope.user_show=data;

});

$scope.send_msg = function($event){
var keyCode = $event.which || $event.keyCode;
if($scope.selected_id==$scope.my_id){
  alert("You can't send msg to your self.");
}else{
  if (keyCode === 13) {
    var data={
      id:$scope.selected_id,
      msg:$scope.msg_text,
      name:$scope.userName
    };
    $scope.msg_text='';
      socket.emit('send msg',data);
    }
  }
};



//Getting the messages from server.
socket.on('get msg',function(data){
  $scope.msgs=data;
  $scope.is_msg_show=true;
  addMessage();
});

// function of push messages to an array.
```

The UI part is very clean, it's user list on which you can click and it will open a chat window where these two user can chat personally. Every thing is happening in client side (such as the user details, msg content etc) except sending the msg to server and getting response from them.
I am stuck in this.

Comment: `var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));`

Comment: I guess you are trying to say `var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.get(port));`

I tried with all these, but of no use.

Comment: No, I meant `var io = require("socket.io").listen(app.listen(app.get("port"), function() { /* */ }));`

Comment: What exactly the function will contain?

Comment: You already have that function at the bottom of your server code. Take what you already have there and wrap it with the socket.io `listen` function.

Comment: Which socket client you are using in `angular`? I recommend using [angular ws](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket), pretty stable